# WebView on React Native Expo project Content-Type

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview, expo

I have a problem with WebView on React Native Expo project.
I have a WebView like this:

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    nativeConfig={{props: {webContentsDebuggingEnabled: true}}}
    ref={webview => { this.myWebView = webview; }}
    source={require('./Resources/indexSummary.html')}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    injectedJavaScript={patchPostMessageJsCode} 
    onMessage={this.onWebViewMessage}
    />
```

The indexSummary.html is:

```
<div class="td">
    <div id="td1"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Utils.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./WebViewBridge.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./TVScriptSummary.js"></script>
</div>
```

When I display WebView, I have these errors:

```
[Error] Refused to execute http://127.0.0.1:19001/assets/src/Graphics/TitleDetail/TVChart/Resources/Utils.js as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
[Error] Refused to execute http://127.0.0.1:19001/assets/src/Graphics/TitleDetail/TVChart/Resources/WebViewBridge.js as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
[Error] Refused to execute http://127.0.0.1:19001/assets/src/Graphics/TitleDetail/TVChart/Resources/TVScriptSummary.js as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
```

Probably this issue is related to Expo content-type returned value.
Can you help to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Can you put your js code inline in html by <script>

Comment: I can't because these files have a external library reference on it. Do you suggest to bundle and minify files before loading?

Comment: Try put  them on the web/http